# How to localize MvcSiteMapNode Tilte with languageresouces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to localize the title attribute for the MvcSiteMapNode.

this is what I have so far:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Key = "Article",  Title = "Article")]
```

and a localication file (*.resx) for german and english, where i have the resource entries

- Article: Article
- Article: Artikel

How can I make it, that the title gets localized.

I found an article, about the `SiteMapNode.ResourceKey Property` but the title property doesn't get translated  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.resourcekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It also seems, that I can't access this property...